# Django custom lookup field raises EmptyResultSet when passed empty set

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have been trying to implement the not_in lookup field, but it generates a different query to ~Q. On querying against a list of ids such as: `ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]` both my `not_in` and `~Q` yield same queryset results although their generated SQL is different. The issue I found with my implementation was that for example querying against an empty list `empty_list` `~Q(id__in=empty_list)` will return all the rows whose ids are not in `empty_list`, in this case, all rows. But with my implementation, it returns an empty queryset.

Code for above implementation for reference

```
from django.db.models.lookups import In as LookupIn

@Field.register_lookup
class LookupNotIn(LookupIn):
    """
    Acts as opposite to `__in`
    """
    lookup_name = "not_in"

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params.extend(rhs_params)

        return "%s NOT IN %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

It generates different SQL to ~Q:

```py
In [28]: print(ShopItem.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=deleted_ids)).query)
```

```sql
SELECT "shop_shopitem"."id", "shop_shopitem"."bakery_id", "shop_shopitem"."name", "shop_shopitem"."is_deleted", "shop_shopitem"."is_visible", "shop_shopitem"."number", "shop_shopitem"."description", "shop_shopitem"."special_information" FROM "shop_shopitem" WHERE NOT ("shop_shopitem"."id" IN (5c6a4164-252a-4aa5-abc1-62cebbc3119a, 6dcbc509-435e-4ccc-a6fd-6a48c652278f, f647ceac-34dd-4e1a-8fcd-ebb255b7d6f9, a1be4bc9-0a10-447f-8215-94df18c53fe2)) ORDER BY "shop_shopitem"."name" ASC
```

```py
In [29]: print(ShopItem.objects.filter(id__not_in=deleted_ids).query)
```

```sql
SELECT "shop_shopitem"."id", "shop_shopitem"."bakery_id", "shop_shopitem"."name", "shop_shopitem"."is_deleted", "shop_shopitem"."is_visible", "shop_shopitem"."number", "shop_shopitem"."description", "shop_shopitem"."special_information" FROM "shop_shopitem" WHERE "shop_shopitem"."id" NOT IN (5c6a4164-252a-4aa5-abc1-62cebbc3119a, 6dcbc509-435e-4ccc-a6fd-6a48c652278f, f647ceac-34dd-4e1a-8fcd-ebb255b7d6f9, a1be4bc9-0a10-447f-8215-94df18c53fe2) ORDER BY "shop_shopitem"."name" ASC
```

My second implementation that actually generates the same SQL as ~Q:

```
@Field.register_lookup
class LookupNotIn(LookupIn):
    """
    Acts as opposite to `__in`
    """
    lookup_name = "not_in"

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params.extend(rhs_params)
        return "NOT (%s IN %s)" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

But when passing am empty set/list as the following:

`print(ShopItem.objects.filter(id__not_in=[]).query)`
it raises error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py in as_sql(self, compiler, connection)
     97                     return '', []
     98                 else:
---> 99                     raise EmptyResultSet
    100             if full_needed == 0:
    101                 if self.negated:

EmptyResultSet:
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Edit:
This seems to occur also with the build-in `__in` lookup field as it is the expected behavior.
The issue here is still that when passed an empty set/list as in `id__not_in=[]`, it will return an empty queryset where it should return every row according to the logic. Somehow `~Q(id__in=[])` does return all rows, and after looking at that generated query for the latter one, it seems that it completely removes the WHERE clause since it would generate `WHERE NOT foo.id IN ()` which is invalid query when passed empty set/list.
it instead just:

```
SELECT "shop_shopitem"."id", "shop_shopitem"."bakery_id", "shop_shopitem"."name", "shop_shopitem"."is_deleted", "shop_shopitem"."is_visible", "shop_shopitem"."number", "shop_shopitem"."description", "shop_shopitem"."special_information" FROM "shop_shopitem" ORDER BY "shop_shopitem"."name" ASC
```

as if we never had a WHERE clause. I am not sure how this is achievable.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. From your explaination it seems like you want to generate a sql query for a exclusive condition. If that's the case than check out exclude() in django orm.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Once you have its queryset than you can change it to an sql query with .query

Comment: @RuchitMicro thank you for your response. I am trying to create a custom lookup field, similar to `__in`, but does the opposite `__not_in`.